# Some URLs are 404 in production

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-7

I have a Laravel 7 project that I deploy using [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) and everything works as expected. A few days later, I created a new route, `/privacy-policy`. I also created a controller and a Blade template. Everything seemed to be working great. However, upon deployment, surprisingly there was a 404 error. All the other links are working fine.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/privacy-policy', 'HomeController@privacy');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function privacy()
{
    return view('app.privacy-policy');
}
```

Even a closure doesn't work.

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('app.privacy-policy');
});
```

I ran the following commands, but it didn't help.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run `php artisan route:list` so that you can verify the URI and name are actually correct? For instance if you see `'app.privacy-policy'` in the URI column then verify that it's named that and also in your controller. Basically fix your route.

```php
Route::get('app.privacy-policy', 'HomeController@privacy')
    ->name('app.privacy-policy');

public function privacy()
{
    return view('app.privacy-policy');
}
```